# The program compiles but terminates on execution. Why?

Tags: c, gcc

```
int main() {  
    char first,second,third,fourth,fifth;  
    scanf("%c %c %c %c %c",first,second,third,fourth,fifth);  
    printf("%c%c%c%c%c",first,second,third,fourth,fifth);  
    getch();  
    return 0;  
}
```

The above program is compile without any error (GNU GCC) but on execution minimizes the 'current window' and terminates again without any error. Why?

**Update**

```
int main() {
    char first,second,third,fourth,fifth;
    scanf("%c %c %c %c %c",&first,&second,&third,&fourth,&fifth);
    printf("%c%c%c%c%c",first,second,third,fourth,fifth);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The above code is the changed after the answers received, but still behaves the same way, just that the compiler does throw any error or even warnings this time.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings (`-W -Wall`).

Comment: `scanf` needs **addresses** where to save the input.

Comment: @phresnel but I am not getting any errors or warning and have included the correct header and recompiled.

Comment: On my box, after including `stdio.h` and `curses.h` (for `getch()`), and compiling with `-lncurses`, it works. It does nothing useful but it works.

Comment: @Edgar I am having XP box and certainly don't think I need curses for `getch()`, it should work otherwise.

Comment: After your update: Post actual warning and error messages; don't just mention that they are there. I guess you don't #include the correct headers, and what you are running now is the previously compiled, buggy binary. Get rid of the `getch()`, programs shouldn't stop unless they are really waiting for input (imho, `getch()` in your case is a bug). Apart from that, `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: @phresnel (Read the my comment above - fourth from top - posted 11 mins ago) It still does not work after removing getch()

Comment: @GVK: How are you attempting to get values into `first`, `second`, ... variables? You run the compiled program and type something? What? You run it with parameters? What? Help us help you here

Comment: @pmg `C:\>gcc prg.c -Wall -Wextra -o prg.exe` used for compiling. `C:\>prg.exe` It should offer to accept input here but instead the dos prompt minimizes and I am back to the editor

Comment: @GVK: just checking ... have you written, compiled, and run the `"hello world" program`? I find it strange that the dos prompt minimizes with your prg.exe ...

Comment: Are you executing it from a command prompt, or running it from Windows Explorer?  Try from a command prompt.

Comment: @GVK: Please add the *complete* sourcecode _AND_ the error message you get. Then we can prolly see further.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're passing uninitialized values into scanf as pointers. Try

```
scanf("%c %c %c %c %c", &first, &second, &third, &fourth, &fifth);
```

Comment: Thanks! Can the `&` be eliminated in `scanf` if I use `char*` instead of `char` when declaring?

Comment: @GVK - Yes, but you must initialze the char* first.

Comment: @icemanind It still does not work after being modified as per the answers, read the update.

Answer (score 2):

When using scanf, you must preface each variable with an Ampersand symbol because you must pass in a pointer to a non-pointer variable, not just a variable itself, like so:

```
scanf("%c %c %c %c %c",&first,&second,&third,&fourth,&fifth);
```

Comment: That's wrong. You might end up passing pointers-to-pointers(to-pointers)* with that overly broad generalization.

Answer (score 2):

## Quick Solution.

Because you are passing char-variables to `scanf` instead of pointers.

```
scanf("%c %c %c %c %c", &first, &second, &third, &fourth, &fifth);
```

## Rule of Thumb.

icemanind mentioned that "When using scanf, you must preface each variable with an Ampersand", but that is too broad. If you stricly follow that rule, you might be passing pointers-to-pointers-... . Instead, as rule of thumb, you must

- *Pass the address of the variable you want to write into*.

and

- *The type of the target must match exactly the specification of the format tokens*,

About the latter: E.g., you are screwed if you pass a double-pointer for the `%d` format token.

## Prevention.

If you had used compiler warnings, in your specific case `-Wformat`, but in the general case just use `-Wall` (and preferably `-Wextra`, too), the compiler would have warned you:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra foo.c

warning.cc: In function `int main()':
warning.cc:4: warning: format argument is not a pointer (arg 2)
warning.cc:4: warning: format argument is not a pointer (arg 3)
warning.cc:4: warning: format argument is not a pointer (arg 4)
warning.cc:4: warning: format argument is not a pointer (arg 5)
warning.cc:4: warning: format argument is not a pointer (arg 6)
```

For the curious: This warning is based on a compiler extension that targets format strings (see gcc's [list of attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes):

> The format attribute specifies that a function takes printf, scanf, strftime or strfmon style arguments which should be type-checked against a format string. For example, the declaration:

```
      extern int
      my_printf (void *my_object, const char *my_format, ...)
            __attribute__ ((format (printf, 2, 3)));
```

Comment: But even after modification it does not work, read the update.

Comment: @GVK: It works for me. I guess you don't #include the correct headers, and what you are running now is the previously, buggy binary.

Comment: I have included `stdio.h` and `conio.h` and recompiled the code.